# How to use single css in a multi-tenant application

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

i'm developing a multi-tenant application with laravel & livewire.
I've a bootstrap template mounted such as a laravel project and i've integrated this template in my project.
For how the template is built, when I am on the `localhost:8000/...` views I get the correct rendering of the template, while when I go to the domain of a tenant, example: `tenant.localhost:8000/...` I completely lose the template.
I noticed that in resources/layout/default.blade to load all css and js there is a for loop that takes the css from the configuration file and loads them into the page

```
{{-- Global Theme Styles (used by all pages) --}}
    @if(!empty(config('dz.public.global.css'))) 
        @foreach(config('dz.public.global.css') as $style)
            <link href="{{ asset($style) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

using `asset($style)` when I go to the tenant domain, it looks for the css in a location that does not exist (the css are under localhost).
I thought of inserting an if-else inside the foreach loop in order to check the domain in the `asset($style)` and make sure that when in the tenant domain the css are searched as if we were in the localhost domain.
It's a good idea? do you have any advice or suggestions?

Comment: If you have a separate Laravel app for each multi-tenant (I doubt that), you can use [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) and set an `env` that will help you with the correct URL. But if you have one app with a lot of subdomains for it, then I have no words, I never faced this problem and is somehow complex.

Answer (score 0):

Now the asset location is changed for each tenant. You could 'hardcode' it.
Something like:

```
<link href='{{ env('APP_URL') }}/location/style.css'>
```

Comment: thanks is the idea I had in mind to use :-)

Comment: I've tried this, and used in all of the parts needed, but i've a strange actions, in the tenant domain I display the template correctly, but clicking on any point of the page I get the error `page expired, refresh the page`, while in the localhost domain I totally lose the template.
I have no idea why it has this behavior

Comment: which packages you're using for multi-tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the url() helper function instead of asset(), since it would generate an absolute path for the assets, this way you can use it in the same way as you use asset() function